# Can't boot from CD/DVD or enter the BIOS on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS in the same PC that I have Windows 8 installed now. I have burned a DVD with the Ubuntu ISO, so now I need to boot the pc from the DVD.

When I access the boot menu on Windows 8, I have only three options:

1. Continue
2. Troubleshot
3. Turn Off your PC

There's no `Use a Device` option, so I can't boot my machine from the DVD/CD. Also I can't access the BIOS, because my keyboard starts working when the operating system is active; before that, the lights are off and pressing <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F8</kbd> or <kbd>DEL</kbd> doesn't work.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by changing the keyboard, now I'm using the one from my other 10-years-old PC that used to use a keyboard with the old-style input (not USB, I don't know it's name). This keyboard is loaded when the machine is turned on, not when Windows is loaded, so now I can press <kbd>DEL</kbd> to enter the BIOS.

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot into to the bios via the Advanced Startup Settings from within Windows 8. Search for advanced startup using the charms bar.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. When clicking on "Restart now" I'm getting the options above: "Continue", "Troubleshot", "Turn Off your PC". Then I turned it off and it boot like always. Any ideas?

Comment: I think troubleshoot would give you the correct options

Comment: I don't think so, there's no useful option there. Can you please be more specific? Thanks.